# Is it possible to customize fusion table( should point my database ) to use fusionTableLayer?

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

I would like to create a Map by the excel sheet values (.csv files too).

By using **FusionTableLayer API,** I think it is possible. At first step we could upload the excel values to the database. Then we create a map by the database annotated value. It is very good idea. This is what I wanted. But One thing is problem to me with FusionTableLayer API is google's Drive has been pointed for the fusion table. It means that all my business data will be shared with google. I don't want to be like that.

Instead of Google's drive My database has to be pointed out. From my database I would like to create a map with FusionTableLayer API. I have been searching through internet, I dont find this is possible. But I believe that it is possible. Please guile me to specify the way to trigger it out ?

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Comment: You can't use the FusionTables API for your own database. But you can implement code to query your database.

Comment: @geocodezip : I am really sorry. I could not understand. Can you please explain little bit ?

Comment: Why do you think it will work?

Comment: @geocodezip : When we can able to retrieve values from Google Drive (It is also database) , Then why we can not retrieve values from our own database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own database, then you cannot use the Fusion Table API as it's meant for the Google Infrastructure. You will have to find another API to take care of this.

One workaround I can suggest to you is to parse points you have as drawing objects for your map. So for each point, create new `google.maps.Marker` with the respective coordinates. Each region can be denoted with `google.maps.Polygon`, and lines with `google.maps.Polyline`. There's plenty more you can do, but it's just a bit more work, and *possibly less secure* depending on your implementation. Furthermore, you can also add info windows to each of those areas using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) by attaching respective listeners to those objects created.

Hope this helps!