# Appengine Fusion tables programmatically creating many map markers

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-fusion-tables

TLDR: I want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168266/is-it-possible-to-customize-fusion-table-should-point-my-database-to-use-fusi), but I am happy to send the data in my database to google as it is created (any user can create a location on the map).

I need to create a lot of map markers on a google map for a website I am creating. Insertions and deletions will be required, but I will never need to filter the data. I found several links showing how to create this map to make it accessible through the use of google docs' spreadsheet, however I have a database of latitude/longitude coordinates in google app engine. My preferred method would be for google to host the map and me to send insertion / deletion queries to the map itself (as the map is constant for all users). This sounded exactly like fusion tables, but I couldn't actually find out how to do it programatically in fusion tables

I know how to create individual points on a map, but there will be a lot of points so sending every single point to the client will be way too slow. My backup plan is simply to use a quad tree and get the client to send the server the bounds of the map and reply with everything in there, but I suspect google has a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the size of your data set and how many insertions and deletions you need to make each day, you might want to consider using the [Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference). You can do a "replaceRows" operation to swap out the entire table contents, or individual "insert" and "delete" calls. (Of course then your data is stored in Fusion Tables.)

You can then [embed](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171211) your map in the website of your choice, or even host it on Google Drive.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, but I couldn't quite understand how to use it. I highly reccommend taking a look here (http://goo.gl/hBaI7) at the sample code google provides for the API.